# React + Firebase undefined using click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hopefully this is a quick fix. Basically, I have set onClick listeners on a few elements of a child component, and when they are clicked, it runs a function from the main component. Everything works good, up until we hit a specific line in the call to the firebase database, where I get issues of undefined. I have included comments to the code below so you know exactly what's going on.

```
getDataName(event) {
    var title;
    var that = this;
    // Grabs data name attribute from element clicked
    var grabIdentifier = event.target.getAttribute('data-name');
    console.log(grabIdentifier); // prints "cruise"

    // Call to firebase
    var greeting = database.ref('events/travel');
      greeting.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log(grabIdentifier); // prints "cruise"

      // Set title to value of the "cruise" key.
      title = snapshot.val().grabIdentifier;
      console.log(title); // prints "undefined" =(

      that.setState({
         greeting : title
       });
    });
  }
```

The idea here is to set the state to the text that is stored as a value under the key of "cruise" in the firebase db. Stumped!

It also might help to mention that if I rewrite the line below, and actually put the word, "cruise" there, it works...which is strange. See below,

```
 title = snapshot.val().cruise;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the property called `grabIdentifier` you need to use bracket notation to access the property name that `grabIdentifier` is referencing

```
title = snapshot.val()[grabIdentifier]
```

for more information on property accessors see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: You sir are a hero. Thank you kindly for the easy solution.

Comment: No problem! happy to help :)