# Return snapshot value Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm new in Firebase and Typrescript. I have the following problem: I want the username of a user from the realtime database.

```
  getUsername(id){
    var username
    firebase.database().ref().child("users/"+id+"/username")
    .once("value",snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.exists()){
        username = snapshot.val();
        console.log("IN"+username)      
      }
    });
    console.log("OUT"+username)
    return username
  }
```

The problem is that outside the if() the username is undefined. I read that with firebase you have to work asynchronously, so I followed this guide:  [How do I return a snapshot.val() from Firebase to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888080/how-do-i-return-a-snapshot-val-from-firebase-to-a-variable/39888472)  so I created the functions:

```
   getListings(id) {
    return firebase.database().ref().child("users/"+id+"/username").once("value");
  }
  
   loadListing(id){
    this.getListings(id).then(this. setListing, this.showError);
}

   setListing(snapshot){
      this.currentSnapshot = snapshot.val()
  }
  
   showError(e){
      console.log(e);
  }
  
   init(id){
      this.loadListing(id);
  }
```

and in other page I call init:

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  username : any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public authService: AuthenticationService) {};
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.init(this.authService.userData.uid)
    console.log(this.authService.currentSnapshot)
  }
}
```

but i receive the error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentSnapshot' of undefined

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `this` in your `setListing` function is no longer referring to the object you expect.

If that is the cause, you might be able to fix it by binding it to the correct object:

```
this.getListings(id).then(this.setListing.bind(this));
```

Comment: I tried with your comment. Now I don't have the error "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentSnapshot' of undefined" . But the line console.log(this.authService.currentSnapshot) returns "undefined"

Comment: Yeah, that's my main concern with the entire code: you're not dealing with the fact the the data is loaded asynchronously consistently. You need to return a promise consistently, consuming the `then()` once doesn't mean the rest of the code can access the values from the database synchronously. My expectation is that `console.log(this.authService.currentSnapshot)` runs before `this.currentSnapshot = snapshot.val()` is executed. Running the code in a debugger (or adding some logging) con confirm that, and bring it back to https://stackoverflow.com/q/40688268